# Flutter: to close a webview when you left the page

Tags: webview, flutter

I have a segmented control and, in one of its pages, I have a webview. I want to close my web view automatically when I change page from the segmented control. Some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may work on the dispose event of your `StateFullWidget` and close your webview when your component or page disposed :

```
@override
void dispose() {
  // close the webview here
  super.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do dispose, just use Navigator.pushReplacement will take care of all.